# Representing a long timestamp as date in elastic search date_histogram aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index with a `ts` field representing epoch ms:

```
"ts": {
    "type": "long"
}
```

Note the type is `long`, not an `epoch_millis` date type.

I run date histogram aggregation on that field:

```
{
    ...
    "aggs": {
       "agg_name": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "ts",
                "interval": "1d",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "min_doc_count": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to aggregate on a per-day documents basis.
The operation runs ok, however a bucket output is as follows:

```
{
    "key_as_string": "yyyy-MM-dd1577836800000",
    "key": 1577836800000,
    "doc_count": 3
}
```

My question is: how can I render `key_as_string` to be something such as `2020-01-01` without changing the field type or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [painless scripting language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.6/painless-walkthrough.html) to achieve what you want but it will not be efficient since painless scripts have a lot of overhead in field manipulation. Here's a scripting way to do this

You can set a format and convert the long to instant of epoch and format it the way you want. As mentioned this is not efficient but will do the work.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "dt_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
           DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
           return df.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['ts'].value));
""",
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since you do not want to modify original fields data type, another way this could be achieved is using [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) fields. In your mapping, if you add a new copy_to field like below and use date datatype then you dont have to run the script and use the fields where its copied to for aggregation.

```
PUT /index_name/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "ts": {
      "type": "long",
      "copy_to": "ts_d"
    },
    "ts_d": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

If you have above mapping, you can use [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to index with new mapping and then use below query which will now work on date datatype.

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
       "agg_name": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "ts_d",
                "interval": "1d",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "min_doc_count": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```